Cylindrical Stress Vessel Problem
I have a cylindrical pressure tank. There are two bulkheads with interface rings on each side. The interface rings and pressure tank have eight holes that are supposed to align. The bulkheads seal off with O-rings.
The holes don't match up perfectly and I can't fit screws into it.
This is a general question. If the diameter of 1 or 3 holes in the pressure tank were drilled larger. Would pressure exerted on those specific enlarged holes be disproportionate to the other smaller holes, making the FOS calculations negative.
I can post more specific information as needed.


Why don't the holes match up? Is the vessel or its part deformed or was it manufactured that way?

The holes in the tank tube were drilled slightly off.

Could you add a picture or drawing of the vessel?

Added and I have FOS calculations. If the holes were not even distributed, it would add an uneven amount of distress, right?

Yes, the uneven distribution of the holes will add some stress. FOS is definitely affected, maybe a better question is if it is still acceptable. For a pressure vessel, this design seems a bit unusual, maybe the pressure is not very high. Could you also add how FOS of this bolted connection was calculated? And is the wall thickness of the cylindrical part uniform or is there some change at the ends around bolts?

Could I send it to you over email? Sorry, this platform makes it difficult to send all the measurements and pictures. joshtouney@gmail.com
